# App Performance Issue

Tags: ios, swift, image, performance

I am doing these functionality :

1. I am doing coloring in image by [Paint Bucket](https://github.com/jflinter/PaintBucket).
2. zoomin zoom out image with scrollview.

Merging these two functionality hangs my device for some time.

Please check below code work and assist me.

**- tap func on imageView**

```
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool{

        let touchView = gestureRecognizer.view

        if touchView == self.imgViewMy{

            let point : CGPoint = touch.location(in: imgViewMy)
            touchedPoint = point

           self.imgViewMy.image = self.imgDup


            // Doing asysn coloring in image to avoid device hang up.
            DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

                print("touch is inside , \(self.touchedPoint!)")

           // Getting scaled coordinates
                let aNewCor = self.getScaledPoint(self.touchedPoint!)

              // Calling Paint Bucket function to change image color. 
                self.imgDup = self.imgDup?.pbk_imageByReplacingColorAt(Int(aNewCor.x),
                                                                       Int(aNewCor.y),
                                                                       withColor: self.colorSel,
                                                                       tolerance: 10)
                self.imgViewMy.image = self.imgDup

           })
       return false
    }
    return false
}
```

**- For Image Zoom in & Zoom Out**

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
     return imgViewMy
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I can help you on this stuff. Did you manage `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale`?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Yeah, `scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0` & `scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0`

Comment: As far as I can see, you are reprocessing `pbk_imageByReplacingColorAt` stuff every time you touch, am I right?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini, But i wanted stop this when I am dealing with scrollview like scrolling image and zooming image, but touch func called before scrollview delegates, thats why, i unable to predict what actual user is doing. So it is also an issue. Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Apologize if I am wrong but, what if you preprocess in a load phase (`viewDidAppear` or something) all the images for every predicted zoom level (assuming you have a range `[1..5]`), and then you stuff everything inside a map (key=zoom level, value=image), so inside your `viewForZooming` you just need to return the right image, doing so: `return map[zoomLevel]` ?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Image is coming from server, second doing this will does not make any animation in the zoom and third is zoom level in b/w 1.0 - 5.0 so it can be any decimal scale also like 2.2, 2.5 ,3.6...etc so it is very complex to work on each & every zoom level. And even it getting very hard to predict zoom level evry time.

Comment: I see, it's quite a complex scenario. Anyway, they do mention about possible performance issues here: https://github.com/jflinter/PaintBucket#performance

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Yeah, thatsy i am using `DispatchQueue.main.async` . Is there any better than `asysnc`. pls let me know. If something probably can be better then this then also pls tell me i will try and check.

Comment: In general if you a little leeway, you might move the cpu intensive process inside a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass)` (you may try various kind of quality of service) and then you leverage on `DispatchQueue.main.async`, only when you need to output your stuff on the main thread.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I tried `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` & `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async`, Both doing same. My screen is not hanged but it colored image very late i mean more late as than expected. Does is there any solution for it?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I do not want to color image when user interacting with scrollview, how can i do this. pls help sir.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I tried the same image with multiple sizes (1024x1024 , 960x960 , 640x640, 512x512), but there is no such productive difference.

Comment: I guess it's better if use the profiler, so you might find some more hints about what is going on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161591/discussion-between-dahiya-boy-and-andrea-mugnaini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make it simple and with a little bit of cleanup:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool{
  let touchView = gestureRecognizer.view
  if touchView == self.imgViewMy {
    let point : CGPoint = touch.location(in: imgViewMy)
    touchedPoint = point
  }
  return true
}

func tapResponse(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
  let aNewCor = self.getScaledPoint(self.touchedPoint!)
  self.imgViewMy.image = self.imgDup?.pbk_imageByReplacingColorAt(Int(aNewCor.x), Int(aNewCor.y), withColor: self.colorSel, tolerance: 5)
}
```

tested on the device, seems to be working fine (it's quite responsive).

Comment: Yeah but when i do zoom it hangs my device.